# Setting up DNS on dual NIC Windows 7 machine

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 machine with two NICs and that sits on two LANs (neither is connected to the internet).

On one LAN the DNS seems to work just fine, I am able to reach other computers on that LAN via computer name.  However, I can't reach machines on the second LAN via name, but IP address does work.

Is there a way to set it up so Windows 7 is able to reach computers on both networks via name?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Make sure the DNS servers you are using have the correct records for all the machines you're trying to reach.